# Horizontal scrolling list

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I would like to have images displayed in a horizontal list.

This is what I've done so far :

```
var list = Ext.create('Ext.List',{
  store: store,
  itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<img src="{icon}" />'),
  inline:true,
  scrollable: {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    directionLock: true
  }
});
```

My store has 5 items, but the list only display two (because the screen is not large enough to display more than two images).

I tried to solve this problem by setting the width of my list to 1000px like so :

```
style:'width: 1000px',
```

All the items are now shown, but now, the problem is the list is not scrollable anymore. I can't go further than the width of the screen.

**[UPDATE]**

I've tried with a hbox panel but nothing is showing. Any idea why ?

```
var hbox = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
  layout:'hbox',
  style:'background-color:red;',
  data: [
              {name: 'Jamie',  age: 100},
              {name: 'Rob',   age: 21},
              {name: 'Tommy', age: 24},
              {name: 'Jacky', age: 24},
              {name: 'Ed',   age: 26}
          ],
  tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('{name}')
});

this.setItems([hbox]);
```

I just see a red background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try passing an object instead of just true for the 'inline' config:

```
var list = Ext.create('Ext.List',{
   store: store,
   itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<img src="{icon}" />'),
   inline: { wrap: false },
   scrollable: {
     direction: 'horizontal',
     directionLock: true
   }
});
```

In the docs, they mention this avoids your wrapping problem and enables horizontal scrolling:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView-cfg-inline.

I did not try it though.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Are you sure, I did a simple trial and it seems to work for me. Can you tell me what is wrong for you in this fiddle: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#X7sxo#6nTmG

Comment: I finally found a link (see my answer to this post) and they also used your method. It's working now.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I finally found this working example which was quite helpful :

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/list-horizontal/index.html

You can also find it in the `examples/production/list-horizontal` when you download Sencha Touch 2

Comment: Possible to assign each row only contain 3 or 4 item?Since the list will show all item in a row

Answer (score 1):

It's not a really good idea (or might be impossible) to create a horizontal `Ext.List`

If you tends to produce something like "image slider" or "carousel", then it would be better if you create an `Ext.Carousel` or something that is more customizable, `hbox`. `Ext.Carousel` is easy and well-documented, so I will talk a little bit more about `hbox`.

The idea is, first you create an empty `hbox` with fixed `height`. Then, you can eventually `add` items to it. Each item is **whatever you like**, for example: `Ext.Image` in your case. Each of your `hbox` item is a component then you can easily customize it the way you want.

Hope this idea helps.

Comment: it's not belongs to `data`, simply `items`. Again, note that my idea is to create a `Ext.Container` with `hbox` layout, so that its child components are arranged horizontally. Each of these items is your item in your "horizontal list"